# Children/young-adult "fantasy" book from 1980s/90s that is really science fiction

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm searching for a book I read as a child in the mid 1990s. Might be older, but had more of a 1980s than 1950s feel to it. I read it in Swedish, but it was probably a translation from English.

I don't remember much of the plot other than that it was about a boy living in a bronze-age/Viking type village.  (I think the book had a lot of Viking or Celtic themes.)  He and his dad were messengers so they ran through the wasteland.  They went on a mission together running to some other village bringing food in parcels.

I think later his dad disappeared during a message run and the boy began searching for him. At some point he found some remnants of a civilization/spaceship/beacon, probably in some cave/cliffs/mountains.  It turned out they were the descendants of some space colonists but had degenerated as a society.  Might also have been a rocket they found.

Something like that; it's a long time since I read it and I can't remember much more.  100-200 pages maybe.

I have read some similar questions and it is not one of the following:

- The Tripods - John Christopher
- Isis books - Monica Hughes

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! If you can take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any extra information that would help with identifying your story.